# ManyToMany relationship from single side need to jpq from other side

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many, jpql

I have to models i.e paymentRecon and waybill. One paymentRecon can have set of waybills under him. But don't want to tightly coupled waybill with it. So i create models like below:

paymentRecon

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class PaymentReconciliation extends BaseEntity {
@Column
private String parentId;
@Column
private BigDecimal grossAmount;
@Column
private String currency;
@Column
private Integer totalNumberOfPackages;
@Column
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PayReconWaybillMap", joinColumns = { 
@JoinColumn(name = "reconId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "waybillId") })
private Set<WayBill> waybill = new HashSet<WayBill>();
}
```

wabill

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 @Entity
 public class PaymentReconciliation extends BaseEntity {
 @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
 private String barCode;
  @Column
  private String consigneeName;
  @Column
  @JsonIgnore
  private String countryCode;

 }
```

Now, i have three tables.
So after developing thing's over it. i need to get waybills which are not attached to any paymentRecon. Can anybody help me how to get this.

Comment: I think you are not showing all the code of your entities (where is the `@Id`?) and the `BaseEntity` code. And why is exists two `PaymentReconciliation`? (I think the last one is the `WayBill` entity). I suppose that `@Id` of the tables is `waybillId` and `reconId`

Answer (score 0):

You can map the "join table" on a new entity `PayReconWaybillMap`, using a `@ManyToOne` on `PaymentReconciliation` to refer to this middle entity:

```
@ManyToOne
private PayReconWaybillMap pwm;
```

And in the `PayReconWaybillMap` entity:

```
@OneToMany
private List<PaymentReconciliation> pr;

@OneToMany
private List<WayBill> wb;
```

So, you can use the JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT wb FROM WayBill wb 
LEFT JOIN PayReconWaybillMap pwm ON pwm.waybillId = wb.waybillId 
WHERE pwm IS NULL
```